# animate panel with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make an animate panel with jquery but my code does not work well, I want your help.
here is my code:

```
jQuery('#style_selector .open').click(function() {
    jQuery('#style_selector').stop(true).animate({"left":"200px"});     
});
jQuery('#style_selector .open').click(function(){
    jQuery('#style_selector').stop(true).animate({"left":"-200px"});        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to attach one event handler and toggle the direction of the animation within. You can also store the selector in a variable to not re-query it over and over:

**JavaScript**

```
var container = $('#style_selector');

container.find('.open').click(function() {
    var direction = null;

    if (!container.data('open')) {
        direction = '+=';
        container.data('open', true);
    } else {
        container.data('open', false);
        direction = '-=';
    }

    container.stop(true).animate({ "left": direction + "200px" });
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/83x7e/)